# Convert a Windows.Form app to a Web App

Tags: c#, visual-studio

An advice, please. Having an app form in c#, what's the best way to turn it into a Web Application? I Use Visuals Studio 2017 professional

Comment: There is no nice automated way to do this @Infoservice .

Comment: Okay, but a way not to lose the written code?

Comment: @Infoservice If you are using three layer architecture, you can use second and third layer DLL in your web. For the first layer ( Presentation layer) you have copy, paste and modify the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot turn a windows forms app into a web app : These are two different technologies and there is no way to move from one to the other.

Maybe you can retrieve some piece of business logic, but no more.